# Which permissions does datastax-agent need?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I am using internal Datastax Enterprise authentication. This means I need to give datastax-agent username and password to access my database. Which privileges does its username need? To which keyspaces? Feel free to refer me to documentation as I haven't found anything on this.

Comment: The c* user used for the agent should have all grants for the opscenter keyspace and describe / select for everything else. I'll work on getting details added to the datastax docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phact wrote:

> The c* user used for the agent should have all grants for the opscenter keyspace and describe / select for everything else. I'll work on getting details added to the datastax docs.